# SQL join not one to one

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
# t1
id | name | description
 1 |  n1  |  d1
 2 |  n2  |  d2
 3 |  n3  |  d3

# t2
id | idt1  | project | url
 1 |   1   |    p1   | u11
 2 |   1   |    p2   | u12
 3 |   2   |    p2   | u22
 4 |   3   |    p1   | u31
```

I want to have a SQL query that displays something like this 2 things:

a) Option 1: Display all elements in t1 for a project p2

```
 t1.name  t2.project   t2.url
    n1        p2         url12
    n2        p2         url22
    n3        p2         null
```

b) Option 2: Display all elements in t1 for all the projects and the select column name to be the project and if data does not exist display null

```
t1.name  t2.project.p1  t2.project.p2 
   n1          url11        null       
   n2          url21        url22
   n3          url31        null
```

For the moment I have only managed to create a part of option 1) using the following query:

```
  select t1.name, t2.project, t2.url from t1
  right join t2 on (t1.id = t2.idt1)
```

Any help?

Comment: Most people find `left join` tricky enough, and find `right join` impossible to understand. If you want to write code easy to maintain, stick to left join if possible.

Comment: ok... but with left join how? I don't know how to do so :(

Comment: `t1 right join t2` has the same result as `t2 left join t1`.

Comment: @jarlh Any idea on option 1 considering using the correct join?

Answer (score 0):

For Option 1) I have found an answer:

```
    select * from
        (select t1.name as name, sp.url as url, sp.ontology as project
        from t1 ph
        left outer join t2 sp on (ph.id = sp.idt1)
        where sp.project = 'p2'

        union

        select t1.name as name, null, null
        from t1 ph
        ) both_tables
    group by both_tables.name;
```

I don't know if this is the optimal, but it works ;) I'm still working on Option 2) to make it automatic no matter how many projects there are.